# SQLAlchemy 2 giving multiple rows on simple one-to-many join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 2 (v2.0.15). I have a one-to-many relationship defined as follows:

```
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = "locations"
    location_pk: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    ...
    facility: Mapped[List["Facility"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="location")

class Facility(Base):
    __tablename__ = "facilities"
    facility_pk: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    location_pk: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("locations.location_pk"))
    ...
    location: Mapped["Location"] = relationship(back_populates="facility")
```

I then want to query all facilities at a given location, one of which has 2 facilities at 1 location. I tried the following (going by example in the Quick Start Guide):

```
stmt = select(Location).join(Location.facility).where(Location.location_pk == 6)
results = session.scalars(stmt)
```

This returns two rows, which appear to me to be identical. Each row has a `facility` property, which has type `<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList'>`, which contain both facilities. I was expecting one row with a list, or two rows each having a different `facility` object. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: SQLAlchemy automatically groups the facilities for you into a nested collection, to make processing one-to-many relationships easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I misunderstood your question.  You can preload the facilities relationship to avoid multiple queries and convert it to the format you want this way.  If you do not want to use the ORM you could use the core layer and python's itertools to aggregate the facilities yourself but you will end up probably just remaking an orm.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, aliased, relationship, joinedload


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = "locations"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    facilities = relationship("Facility", back_populates="location")

class Facility(Base):
    __tablename__ = "facilities"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    location_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("locations.id"))
    location = relationship("Location", back_populates="facilities")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    l1, l2 = Location(id=1), Location(id=2)
    session.add_all([l1, l2])
    f1, f2, f3 = Facility(id=1), Facility(id=2), Facility(id=3)
    session.add_all([f1, f2, f3])
    l1.facilities.append(f1)
    l2.facilities.append(f2)
    l2.facilities.append(f3)
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    # use joinedload to preload the facilities relationship
    # use unique() to prevent duplicate locations
    # use scalars() to return single locations instead of 1-tuples with a location in them
    # use all() to get locations into list
    locations = session.scalars(select(Location).options(joinedload(Location.facilities))).unique().all()


    for location, facilities in ((location, list(location.facilities)) for location in locations):
        print (location, facilities)


    for location in locations:
        print (location, list(location.facilities))
```

The use of `unique()` here is explained in the migration docs for 2.0 found here [orm-rows-not-uniquified-by-default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#orm-rows-not-uniquified-by-default).

Furthermore with regards to this example there are cases you might want a traditional query like this:

```
SELECT locations.*, facilities.* FROM locations LEFT OUTER JOIN facilities ON locations.id = facilities.location_id
```

The result of this query is going to contain duplicates for locations with more than 1 facility because that is just how SQL works.  Like this:

| locations.id | ... | facilities.id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | 1 | ... |
| 1 | ... | 2 | ... |
| 2 | ... | 3 | ... |
| 3 | ... | NULL | ... |

In this case though we have asked SQLAlchemy to automatically gather up the facilities for each location and insert them into its facilities attribute and unique is implicit but SQLAlchemy wants you to explicitly apply `unique()` so there is no confusion.  I'm pretty sure this is based on the experience of it being really confusing for people when things happen "magically".

Comment: This sort of works, but I was looking for a query which returns an iterable for all locations, with facilities nested under each. e.g. Location 1 (Fac 1), Location 2 (no facility), Location 3 (Fac 2, Fac 3), etc... by original query does this but the locations are repeated.

Comment: I updated my answer, this is more along what Barmar was saying.  SQLAlchemy is going to aggregate the facilities for you using the ORM.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The .unique() on session.scalars() did what I needed. I still don't understand why it's needed though. If you have a one to many relationship and you do the join, I would expect either 1 row with an iterable for the many returned, or multiple rows, each having one of the many as a non-iterable, but not multiple rows each having the many iterable. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, especially with eager load but for a traditional `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL it wouldn't make sense.  I included a link and tried to give a better explaination of why it is there.

Comment: Just to add, SQLAlchemy is not meant to be an air tight abstraction, it is just a toolkit to write SQL faster, safer, better, etc.  You still are making queries against the database and a lot of corner cases are going to come up.